# Creating virtual network attached storage with VMware

Tags: linux, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have recently began using VMware virtual machines to develop kernel modules for Linux. Currently, I am working on a module that requires a storage device attached over the network. I do not actually have the resources at the moment to create an actual network device that I can link to from inside the virtual machine. I would like to know, what is the proper way of simulating a Storage Area Network (SAN) in VMware?

For some extra context, the module forwards I / O requests at the block level to a remote disk and retrieves the results.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "designating it as being remote". A standalone disk is a piece of metal, if there is no software to handle it. Could you pls explain?

Comment: I was under the impression that I could create virtual disks apart from virtual machines and attach / remove them on the fly from running vm's. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Absolutely. However, a disk that you attach/detach is not quite the same as a NAS, which is a dedicated pc with a large disk ready for read and/or write access to anyone on the network (plus backup software....). The closest you can come is by sharing the detachable disk, but it would still be a locally mounted disk, not a Network Attach device.

Comment: In that case, it would appear that I should create a second virtual machine with a large virtual disk attached to it to act as the NAS.

Comment: Right. There are many open source operating systems available for NASes, like FreeNAS, NAS4Free, or OpenMediaVault.

Comment: From what you wrote I guess you could mean [SAN (storage area network)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network) rather than [NAS (network-attached storage)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage). Very simply said SAN is really a specialized device which provides access to sectors of the storage (over Fibre Channel, iSCSI etc.) while NAS is just a specialized file server which provides network file system like SMB/CIFS or NFS.

Comment: I think that is what I meant to ask. I updated the question.

Comment: My understanding is that a [SAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network) appears to the operating system as a hard disk, so as far as any applications are concerned, there's no difference between accessing a regular hard drive, and accessing a SAN.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to present an RDM (Raw Device Mapping) to the VM for true block level access.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but it would be useful to write a little bit more - mainly about relation to the problem described in the question.